# How to avoid conflict in GIT

Tags: git, conflict

**Background**: We are using GIT as a PHP deploy system (in addition to SCM features). Once we have a stable source code version, we launch a script that is executed in the *production server* to synchronize with the latest version. This *production server* has two branches:

- *master*: that's the latest version of the source code without any *production* customization.
- *pro*: that's a *master* child branch that only exists in **this** *production server* and has some small changes necessary to run the app in the given *server* (i.e. database access data, server name, etc).

*NOTE*: The main repository has more branches and programmers have more branches, but the only branch used in production is *master*, the other are ignored and not synchronized.

**The problem**: There are about 100 copies of the source code in different *servers* with different configurations and there is a unique script that launches all "local" scripts. Until now local scripts have never failed due it's simplicity, a bit more than:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout pro
git rebase master
```

(I've removed all non-GIT commands and the error checking)

but now all script have failed because there is a conflict between a change we have made in the main repository and a change that every local *pro* branch has (remember that the *pro* branch is not shared, just local to store some configuration).

Concretely, the problem has appeared when we have changed a couple of lines in a file called '*config.php*' from this:

```
$db_user = 'user';
$db_password = 'password';
```

to this:

```
$db_user = 'other-user';
$db_password = 'other-password';
```

The conflict appears in the *pro* branch when the script executes the '*rebase*' because the *production server* has a different value for these variables:

```
$db_user = 'pro-user';
$db_password = 'pro-password';
```

Of course the conflict is really easy to avoid "by hand" just ignoring the "new configuration" that comes from the repository (*pro* config shouldn't be changed).

The question is: how can I avoid this conflict? Because we don't want to resolve the conflict by hand on every *ŝerver* every time we find this kind of conflict. We can change the script without any problem if it's necessary, temporary or permanently to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to override the conflicts by automatically selecting the content of `pro`'s commits, after checking out `pro`, run with these parameters: `git rebase -X theirs master`.

Note that the sides switch between merge and rebase, so when rebasing - `ours` becomes `master`, and `theirs` is the commits you have in your current branch which are not in `master`. Which is kind of counter-intuitive.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this strategy will overwrite the *pro* commits over the master ones. Isn't it? If that's correct, that's what I was looking for :)

Comment: Yes. But use it carefully. You must be sure that all your 100 copies (pro branches) don't have any other commit by mistake, otherwise you'll end up with something you didn't intend to.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not particularly concerned about security with these usernames and passwords, one option would be to set an environment variable on each machine with the relevant user/pass. E.g., in your .bashrc file or equivalent for each machine, put

```
export SERVER_USER="usernamehere"
export SERVER_PASS="passwordhere"
```

Then in your php code, call the environment variables with `getenv()`:

```
$db_user = getenv('SERVER_USER');
$db_password = getenv('SERVER_PASS');
```

Comment: Yes, that's an option for this case (excluding security concerns), but I would like something more general for possible future cases where the conflict happens in a piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to have this configuration in the same file that you branch for each environment? I'd consider having one file per configuration and let them diverge by design. This more or less requires that you can isolate the configuration-specific parameters so that a change that should affect all configuration doesn't require changes in hundreds of files.

Branching a file and forking it in two or more copies are conceptually very close (and some version control systems don't distinguish between the two cases). It's not obvious that branching is the right choice in your case.

Comment: In this particular case it's correct your approach, but I would like to be prepared to a future change where the change (conflict) affect to a piece of PHP code.

Comment: That type of automatic conflict resolution when deploying sounds like a recipe for disaster. While it's likely that merging with `-X ours` produces correct results it's not safe.

Comment: Of course, this will be used under certains circunstances and testing the results before deploying to all servers. Anyway, thanks for the advice.